# JavaScript function default parameters

Tags: javascript, function

```js
const add = (a = 1, b = 1, c = 1) => a + b + c
add(4, , 2)
```

Throws Uncaught SyntaxError, unexpected token ','

How do I call the function so b defaults to the value 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#passing_undefined_vs._other_falsy_values) as value.

```js
const add = (a = 1, b = 1, c = 1) => a + b + c
console.log(add(4, undefined, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Pass `undefined` as value**

Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#passing_undefined_vs._other_falsy_values

```js
const add = (a = 1, b = 1, c = 1) => a + b + c
console.log(add(4, undefined, 2))
```